# Outlook dark mode on background-color of text link messes up

Tags: html, css, email-templates

On outlook dark mode, weird background-color of text inside `<a>` tag appears (only when anchor tag has href link to it ) when I already. I tried setting background-color to a:link and various other methods but it just doesn't seem to be fixed. Any idea ?

The code below looks fine almost all apps but on certain Outlook dark mode, highlighted background color appears.

```
  <div style="margin-top: 10px; "><!--[if mso]>
     <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:48px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:155px;" arcsize="17%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#4e40ef">
                <w:anchorlock/>
                <center>
              <![endif]-->
               <a href="http://google.com"
            style="background-color:orange; color:white; text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:155px;">Click here</a>
              <!--[if mso]>
                </center>
              </v:roundrect>
            <![endif]--></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the background-color on the `<div>` to the same background-color as the problematic `<a>` tag that's inside of it? That might smooth out the color gaps.